# django template to call js object

Tags: javascript, django, onload

how to do this in django.

```
<body onload="main_(1);"> </body>.
```

I tried it with this.

```
{ load static }
<body>
  {% if true %}
    <script src="{% static 'main/js/main_index.js' %}" ></script>
    <script>
      main_(1);
    </script>
  {% endif %}
</body>
```

No luck so far. is there an easier way.

Comment: Why can't you just do what you had originally, with it in the body tag? What's the point of the `if true` condition? And what do you mean, "no luck"?

Answer (score 0):

In your `if` template tag: it's `True` not `true`.

**Try:**

```
{ load static }
<body>
  {% if True %}
    <script src="{% static 'main/js/main_index.js' %}" ></script>
    <script>
      main_(1);
    </script>
  {% endif %}
</body>
```

**or:**

```
{ load static }
<body onload="main_(1);">
    <script src="{% static 'main/js/main_index.js' %}" ></script>
</body>
```

**Make sure the file `main_index.js` is loaded in the network tab of the browser devtools**

I hope this will help.